# MVC LInk from Web Config AppSettings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I created a new mvc 2 project to learn mvc. I'm trying to do something like the following:
Webconfig

```
<appSettings>
      <!-- WEB SITES -->
      <add key="LiveWebAddress" value="www.mydomain.org"/>
      <add key="DevWebAddress" value="localhost/mydomain"/>
      <add key="TestWebAddress" value="test-2/mydomain"/>          
 </appSettings>
```

in the controller I am trying to do this:

```
public ActionResult link()
{
   //return View();
   return RedirectToAction(
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                  .AppSettings["LiveWebAddress"]
                  .ToString()
   );               
}
```

Am I headed in the right direction? I'm getting a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) instead. In addition, I'm not sure doing this in the controller is the best option.

Comment: In your opinion what would be the best option?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do Live Dev and Test point to the site you are developping here or to another site?

Comment: I'm just trying to find a simple way to swap out the links based on the environment. When we deploy to our live address we want the link to be livewebaddress, etc.. so I'm trying to swap the values using web.confg transforms.

Comment: @MissioDei : I have the same problem as you, what was the solution that you went for?